# Fatal Error on Magento Order Cancellation from customer My Account

Tags: php, magento

I am getting an error on my magento 1.9 while canceling the order from customer my account. I am using to commercebees extension to extend the cancel option at customer my account section

Extension URL : https://www.commercebees.com/order-cancellation-module-make-it-easy-for-your-customers/

Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line of app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php:

```
if ($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() != 'free') {
```

That means `$order->getPayment()` returns false.

You may try to verify:

1. If the order you need to cancel has a correct payment method. Maybe the payment method is custom or was customized. Try to verify if it has the same error when canceling an order with other payment method has the same error.
2. Try to disable the commercebees extension in it's configuration file in the app/etc/modules directory. Set `<active>false</active>`
3. If Magento default canceling (from admin panel) an order works without errors.

If the error takes place because of commercebees extension you may apply for help to their support team.